# Split string to hash table using LINQ

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have:

```
string s = "A=1,B=2,C=3";
```

I need the output in hashtable using LINQ.

Hastable should be filled as

```
["A"] | 1

["B"] | 2

["C"] | 3
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code:

```
var dict = s.Split(',')
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Split('=').First(),
                          x => int.Parse(x.Split('=')[1]));
```

Be aware that this code breaks if the input string is not in a valid format. Additionally, it uses the strongly typed and preferred `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead of `Hashtable`.

**UPDATE:**

To avoid splitting twice when creating the dictionary, you can use the following code:

```
var dict = s.Split(',')
            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(x => x[0],
                          x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

Comment: Can't you avoid having to split twice?

Comment: Hmm.. tried to mess with the `.ToDictionary` to have *return* something but so far failed - can't such thing be done? :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I updated again. Please have a look. I don't really know what you mean by "return something" from ToDictionary.

Comment: Neat! Disregard my previous comment, didn't understand how the `.ToDictionary()` worked. Looks like ideal solution now, cheers! :)

Comment: I was just about to say that you don't need to create an intermediate object when splitting the substrings, but I see that you already copied my code. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string, then split each substring to get the key-value pairs:

```
Dictionary<string, int> values =
  s.Split(",")
  .Select(x => x.Split("="))
  .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => Int32.Parse(x[1]))
```

This returns a `Dictionary<T,T>` rather than a `HashTable`, which is practically obsolete. You can create a `HashTable` from the `Dictionary` if that is really needed:

```
HashTable pairs = new HashTable(values);
```